# ARM 32bit - moving 4 byte floating point number to register

Tags: assembly, arm

Say I have an instruction like this
`MOV R0, #0x3FC00000`

This would move the floating point number `1.5` (approximately) into register R0, with the assembled bytes for this instruction being `FF 05 A0 E3`.

Now if I want to move a floating point number `0.0875` to register R0, how would I go about this? `0x3db33333` requires 32 bits, which fits in a register, but not a single instruction. How many instructions are required?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One, if you load from memory. Two if you use immediates.

Comment: I don't have any ability to load it from memory here, as I am patching an existing program. So I will most likely have to jump and write my own code.

Comment: @Neo How so?  Can't you use `ldr r0, =0x3db33333` and let the assembler figure out the gritty details?

Comment: Then `mov`  + `movt` or the `mov32` pseudoinstruction which generates such a pair.

Comment: @fuz Just edited my comment, I'm patching an existing program.

Comment: Or depending on what you have in the registers you might be able to calculate it in one instruction.

Comment: @Neo Ah, that makes sense.  Then use `mov` and `movt` as Jester described.

Comment: Right, so to my understanding as this is an existing program: I need to replace the MOV instruction with a branch to a code cave, and write my own subroutine to execute those two instructions.

Comment: If you can do that, then you can just place the constant there and load it from memory without having to branch back and forth.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks.

Comment: @old_timer why wouldn't mov+movt work?

Comment: armv7-a was not specified if armv7-a then two instructions/words would work mov+movt, but a pc-relative load would work as well, two words of binary.  Otherwise if it has to be instructions then it is four instructions, four words of binary.  being a jump then b, mov pc relative b, word or b, mov, movt, b, or b, mov, orr, orr, orr, b.  so four words minimum all said and done.  if you have branch reachable space then the pc-relative load may fit nicely and only cost two words.  cheaper than four

Comment: which is what you said